# Website is scrolling horizontally to the right on mobile when there is no visible content there

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

As the title says, the website is scrolling to the right when there is no content there.

I can only recreate this when using it on an actual mobile device.

Currently working on transferring it over, that's why the link is currently like that.

http://georgecohen-co-uk.php5.hostingweb.co.uk/

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remember that questions should be helpful to future readers. Don't link to external websites that will change in time making the referencing question useless. Please post the code that reproduces the issue (or a minimal example) in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a problem with animations? Maybe div which is sliding on the load expand ur page in horizontal.
Learn more about animations.

Or in CSS add

```
html, body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight, turns out it was the loading wipe creating the extra space. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

It might fix your problem

Answer (score -1):

Try coloring your divs and /or respective borders so you can track down the issue. I would maybe use firebug or other equivalent plugin/ embedded browser tool